# Find the solution of partial differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve following exercise:

Find the solution

$$
    xu_{x}+yu_{y}=0
$$
$$
    u(0,y)=g(y)
$$

And consider if solutions are unambiguous. Whether g have to meet some conditions?

I came to the conculsion that solutions of u are form:

$$
u(x,y)=f(\frac{x}{y})
$$

I tried do something like this

$$
f(\frac{0}{y})=g(y)
$$
But I've stucked. Could anyone help me solve it?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Perhaps you could make the ansatz $u=X(x)Y(y)$ and use separation of variables.

Answer (score 1):

Using separation of variables, let $u(x,y) = X(x)Y(y)$, the equation becomes
$$ xX'Y + yY'X = 0 $$
$$ x\frac{X'}{X} + y\frac{Y'}{Y} = 0 $$

Thus
$$ x\frac{X'}{X} = \lambda $$
$$ y\frac{Y'}{Y} = -\lambda $$

This gives the solution
$$ u(x,y) = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^n $$

$u(0,y) = a_0$, so the equation only has a solution if $g(y)$ is a constant function